# Android - FCM problem with "notification" key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm with a problem here.

I have a logic with deep links in my push notification.

This is the FCM's json now:

```
{
"to": token_here",
"data": {
    "DEEP_LINK_PATH": "STRING_HERE",
},
"notification": {
    "title": "Teste",
    "body": "Push de teste"
}
}
```

As you can see, all the logic for deep links is inside `DATA`, as usual.

When my app is open, everything looks fine.
But when its close, or in background, not working because its not passing inside my `FirebaseMessagingService`. Its seens like the notification is creating automatic by Android with base in `NOTIFICATION` body and title.

Is there a way to continue using this model of json and receive `FirebaseMessagingService` be call in background too?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has two basic types of messages:

- Notifications messages

  These messages are delivered to your application code when the app is active, and are handled by the system (Android in your case) when your app is not active. The system displays them as a notification in the system tray in that case.
- Data messages

  These messages are always delivered to your application code, no matter if the app is active or not. Your application code can either display a message when it receives a data message, or process it in any other way you see fit.

So it sounds like you're looking for a data message.

Also see:

- the [documentation on message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)
- the [documentation on sending messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices)